# Returning vector with Weaviate

Tags: weaviate

I am considering using Weaviate as a vector store. I see on the docs that you can set the vectorizer to none and provide custom vectors in addition to the other metadata. After I do that I want to get all the metadata back using the Get{} query, as well as the vectors. Does Weaviate support returning the vector as well as the metadata?

I see in the demo they add vector to the additional properties and it seemed to return the vector associated with the object. Is this in fact simply returning the vector associated with results or is it tied to specifying some kind of search query like nearText?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's certainly possible.

```
{
  Get{
    Article(
      nearText: {
        concepts: ["music"]
      }  
      limit: 3
    ){
      title
      _additional {
        vector # <== this is what you're looking for
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- You can also try it out [here](https://link.semi.technology/3P7WdxF)
- [Additional property docs](https://weaviate.io/developers/weaviate/current/graphql-references/additional-properties.html)